# Python tkinter, restart the program

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

this is simple example of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random


class A:

    def __init__(self, master):
        n = random.randrange(1, 10, 1)
        self.frame_a = Frame(master)
        self.frame_a.pack()
        self.label_a = Label(self.frame_a, text=n)
        self.label_a.pack()

    def clean(self):
        self.frame_a.destroy()
        A(root)
        B(root)


class B:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame_b = Frame(master)
        self.frame_b.pack()
        self.button_b = Button(self.frame_b, text='again', command=self.do_again)
        self.button_b.pack()

    def do_again(self):
        self.frame_b.destroy()
        hello.clean()


root = Tk()
hello = A(root)
world = B(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I want delete all frames and label and restart the program. But it doesn't work correctly. When I first time use button `again`, it works. However If I click button again, frame won't destroy.

EDIT:
This is sample of my code:

```
class GamePick:

    def __init__(self):
        #there are also some labels and frames but they relate to my problem

    def do_black_jack(self):
        global bj
        global bj_play
        ''' You pick Black Jack, open new window and close actual window'''
        bj = Toplevel(self.master)
        bj_play = BjGui(bj)
        bj['bg'] = 'springgreen4'
        bj.wm_geometry("1500x900")
        Choices.close(my)

class BlackJack:

   #There are some function for pick new card for player and dealer

    def check_limit(self):#
        if sum(player_cards_val) > 21:
            if 11 in player_cards_val:
                    player_cards_val.remove(11)
                    player_cards_val.append(1)
                    self.check_limit()
            else:
                    bj_play.show_result(res='Dealer win')
        elif sum(bot_cards_val) > 21:
            if 11 in bot_cards_val:
                    bot_cards_val.remove(11)
                    bot_cards_val.append(1)
                    self.check_sixteen()
            else:
                    bj_play.show_result(res='Player win')
        else:
            if sum(player_cards_val) > sum(bot_cards_val):
                    bj_play.show_result(res='Player win')
            else:
                    bj_play.show_result(res='Dealer win')



class BjGui:


    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.bot_frame = Frame(self.master, height=False, width=False, bg='springgreen4')
        bj.wm_geometry("1500x900")
        self.bot_frame.pack(side='top', pady=20)
        self.player_frame = Frame(self.master, height=False, width=False, bg='springgreen4')
        bj.wm_geometry("1500x900")
        self.player_frame.pack(side='bottom', pady=20)
        self.buttons_frame = Frame(self.master, bg='springgreen4')
        self.buttons_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        # There are function for this class, they show players cards and bots cards from class Black Jack


    def show_result(self, res):#This function, create new label and button.
                               #  New label show result of the game, after I click button, it should will restart 
        self.info_label = Label(self.master, text=res, font=('aharoni', 60), bg='springgreen4', pady=35)
        self.info_label.pack()
        self.again_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.again_frame.pack()
        self.again_bt = Button(self.again_frame, text='play again', font=('times', 12), command=self.do_again, bg='blue')
        self.again_bt.pack()

    def do_again(self):# This should delete all frames and clear list with cards and restart game, but it doesn't work
        self.info_label.destroy()
        self.again_frame.destroy()
        self.player_frame.destroy()
        self.bot_frame.destroy()
        self.buttons_frame.destroy()
        bot_cards_key.clear()
        bot_cards_val.clear()
        player_cards_key.clear()
        player_cards_val.clear()
        no_repeat.clear()
        BlackJack()
        BjGui(bj)
```

I would like to create Black Jack game. `class BlackJack` picks new cards for player and dealer, compare value of these cards, and determite who is winner. `class BjGui` shows players and dealers cards, there some buttons frames and labels. When the game ends, I use function `check_limit`, it determites who is winner and function `show_result` create new label with result and new button. This button should be able restart the game.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want the object recursion that you have.
You're making new `A`s and `B`s inside the current `A` that you're working with - the top of the stack.
`hello` and `world` only refer to the bottom of the stack, not to all the other `A`s and `B`s in your object recursion stack.

Also, I'm not sure why you want two different classes or two different frames. I would have to understand what you want to give a suggestion on how to do it with different frames and classes.

```
from tkinter import *
import random


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = Tk()

        self.frame_a = None
        self.label_a = None  # not necessary, but common styling preference
        self.button_b = None  # not necessary, but common styling preference

        self.clean()
        self.master.mainloop()

    def clean(self):
        if self.frame_a is not None:
            self.frame_a.destroy()
        n = random.randrange(1, 10, 1)
        self.frame_a = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame_a.pack()
        self.label_a = Label(self.frame_a, text=n)
        self.label_a.pack()
        self.button_b = Button(self.frame_a, text='again', command=self.clean)
        self.button_b.pack()


hello = A()
```

Comment: @Marty See the last two lines of your sample? You're creating new objects inside the existing object. This doesn't replace the existing objects. It doesn't reset the existing objects. Don't create new objects. Just change the state of the existing objects to how you want them.